# 200 status for requests from IP not allowed by htaccess?

Tags: security, .htaccess, apache2, log-files

I have a Debian 9 server which is continually beaten on by bots.  I check the access logs for 200s every day just to be sure my countermeasures are working. The logs are full of 403 status requests with usually only a handful of 200s from allowed IPs. IP addresses edited below for privacy.

Doc root has the following htaccess file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from  216.xx.xxx.xxx
allow from 184.xxx.xxx.xxx

AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthName "Admin"
AuthType Basic

<Limit GET>
        require valid-user
</Limit>
```

On an ordinary day this command only yields accesses for the two IPs above and for ::1

```
sudo zcat /var/log/apache2/access.log.4.gz | awk '{ if($9 == 200) { print $1 " " $7  } }' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10
```

But today we also had what appear to be two requests which got a 200 status despite not being in the htaccess as allowed.

```
::1 - - [17/Apr/2020:00:49:05 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.2r (internal dummy connection)"
103.231.90.xxx - - [17/Apr/2020:00:49:36 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1" 200 2670 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 [en] (X11, U; OpenVAS-VT 9.0.3)"
103.231.90.xxx - - [17/Apr/2020:00:49:39 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1" 200 163 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 [en] (X11, U; OpenVAS-VT 9.0.3)"
::1 - - [17/Apr/2020:00:49:52 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.2r (internal dummy connection)"
```

Do those represent successful accesses?  If so, how do I correct my htaccess file so this is not possible?  I thought it was already solid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`OPTIONS *`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) with a wildcard refers to the entire server, whereas the `.htaccess` file equals `<Directory>` [configuration section](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html). If you want to disallow these requests, you'd need to move your directives from `.htaccess` to `<VirtualHost>` or global server configuration.

BTW, Debian 9 comes with Apache 2.4, which has different [access control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) directives from what you are using:

- Apache 2.2:

  ```
  order deny,allow 
  deny from all 
  allow from 216.xx.xxx.xxx 
  allow from 184.xxx.xxx.xxx
  ```
- Apache 2.4:

  ```
  Require ip 216.xx.xxx.xxx 184.xxx.xxx.xxx
  ```